# return undefined Posts.findOne();

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, collections

I am pretty new in Meteor so I am following the Discove Meteor Book. But I found some troubles. When it says: open the browser console in two new windows (chap 4-collections):

- Firstly, It cannot let me open 2 windows at the same time. It only deploys one console window (It seems to belong to the whole browser system.)
- Secondly, ok I just will work with one browser console window. However when I am trying to run Posts.findOne(); it should deploy 
  {title: "A new post", _id: LocalCollection._ObjectID}; But it deploys "undefined". Actually I do not get it because I have this : `Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts')`; (filename: posts.js) under the lib folder (which should work in both sides (client and server).

any ideas about why is Undefined?

Comment: Sounds like a publish / subscribe issue, did you reach this chapter in the book ?

Comment: you'll need to post your code. It looks like your Posts collection is empty. Regarding the former question, that's a question about your browser. Which browser do you use? In most browsers you can have a console for each tab/window.

Comment: @ChristianFritz ok, I got a browser console for each window (mozilla firefox). My code is the one who I wrote in my first question (or what do yoy meant?. I inserted one object with this cmd:  db.posts.insert({title: "A new post"}); in Mongodb shell it shows this object but not in the browser console. Besides, I inserted a second one in the browser console running this cmd: Posts.insert({title: "A second post"}); However when I run this:
Posts.find().count(); its outcome is 0 when it has to be 2. In mongoDB console/shell it is ok as it should be.

Comment: I have not reached this chapter yet. @saimeunt . But I am following the book and it should deploy : { "_id": ObjectId(".."), "title" : "A new post"}; But it deploys undefined

Comment: Javiss, can you check if you still have a package called autopublish? Type meteor list into your Terminal

Comment: @MichelH No, I do not have it.

 accounts-password  1.1.1  Password support for accounts
coffeescript       1.0.6  Javascript dialect with fewer braces and semicolons
insecure           1.0.3  Allow all database writes by default
meteor-platform    1.2.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
twbs:bootstrap     3.3.5  The most popular front-end framework for developing...
underscore         1.0.3  Collection of small helpers: _.map, _.each, ...

Comment: Can you please do: meteor add autopublish. If you've done that check the browser console for published records.

Comment: @MichelH It works !!! thanks :=) I do not know why the book does not say anything about adding this package at this point. anyways, it works.

Comment: I am not sure if the book is mentioning it .. when you create a new meteor project it is added by default.

Comment: @MichelH well it seems that the package was not added by default in my case. I just was following the book.. so maybe it has some bug the new version of meteor..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just like `insecure`, all new Meteor apps are created with the `autopublish` package.
If you `meteor remove autopublish` you need to publish your collections content and subscribe to it. If you haven't done so, you won't see any records since the client does not pull data from the server, this adds security measures to Meteor.

To solve: `meteor add autopublish` then check the browser console for published records.

Comment: @Kyll, sorry about that. I answered this in the comments above and added the answer so it is not unanswered. I can't delete the answer anymore since it is the accepted answer and helped the user.